# ”//…” in <script> tag is interpreted as “file://” in electron

Tags: node.js, electron, addthis

I'm trying to include external AddThis widget in Electron.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"></script>
```

The issue is that

`//` in `<script>` tag is interpreted as `file://`.

And the app errors with

```
GET file://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

This can be easily fixed by adding `http(s):` before `//`. But huge mess happens if included *js* includes *js'es* starting with `//`. For example, `addthis_widget.js` includes 36 relative URLs starting with `//`

Such behavior takes place, because base URL in electron started with `file:` when application loaded: `mainWindow.loadUrl('file:///index.html')`. Then the relative URLs starting with `//` automatically resolved to `file:` and not `http(s):` But its not very clear how to revert things back.

Kindly help.

---

Adding js directly to the app is not an option, since AddThis modifying remote script(s) too often.

Comment: Your best bet, I think, is to bundle that javascript file in your app and modify the urls in it (instead of loading it from CDN)

Comment: Thanks Sergio. But the script is updated too frequently by AddThis. I will mention it in my post

Comment: Of course. In this case, I'd post a support ticket, or something.

Comment: Somebody [asked the same question in the atom forum](https://discuss.atom.io/t/in-script-tag-is-interpreted-as-file/19232/13).

Comment: Yep. I just looked trough it. Unfortunately it wasn't resolved there :(